# Python - converting multiple lines to one

Tags: python, function, output

I have a question concerning some python code that I have written:

```
def read_graph_from_file(filename):

   txtfile = open(filename, "rU")

   node_memory = 0
   neighbour_list = 0

   for entry in txtfile:
       entry_without_newline = entry.replace('\n',"")
       columns = entry_without_newline.replace(','," ")
       columns = columns.split(" ")
       number_of_columns = len(columns)

       if number_of_columns == 2:
           neighbour_list = columns
           neighbour_list.sort()

           if node_memory == float(neighbour_list[0]):
               y = neighbour_list[1]
               print y
```

The output I want from this is a list, i.e. [1,4]. Instead I am receiving the characters across multiple lines, i.e:

1

4

I was wondering how I might rectify this?

Comment: You're printing `y` individually, which will result in a new line per iteration. Instead, append to a list first, then print the list at the end.

Comment: You can also use `print y,` to print a space instead of a newline, or accumulate a string to point out, etc. But if you want to print a list, the obvious thing to do is to create a list, as @JesseMu says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them in a list, you will have to create a list variable and just append your results to it. You should return this list once your function is done.

```
def read_graph_from_file(filename):

   txtfile = open(filename, "rU")

   node_memory = 0
   neighbour_list = 0

   lst = []

   for entry in txtfile:
       entry_without_newline = entry.replace('\n',"")
       columns = entry_without_newline.replace(','," ")
       columns = columns.split(" ")
       number_of_columns = len(columns)

       if number_of_columns == 2:
           neighbour_list = columns
           neighbour_list.sort()

           if node_memory == float(neighbour_list[0]):
               y = neighbour_list[1]
               lst.append(y)
   return lst
```

Then if you run your function like this:

```
print read_graph_from_file(<fileName>)
```

You will get the desired result:

```
[1,4]
```

Alternatively, you can print the resulting list directly at the end of your function. Then you won't have to call the function with `print`.